# How to send SMS using WAP in android?

Tags: android

I need to send SMS without displaying the number of the sender. The name of sender should be displayed while receiving the SMS. I heard WAP can be used to send that type of sms with only name and not the number. But I don't have any idea how to apply that. Can anybody please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to make use of a [SMS gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway) if you want to deliver an SMS using a data connection. Make use of an SMS gateway API such as [this](http://www.mysmsmantra.com/api.html).